# Reading .htacces on centos

Tags: apache, .htaccess, centos6

I am hoping someone can help. I am quite stuck.

I am struggling to get apache to read my .htaccess file for a one or two sites which are set up in exactly the same way as sites that are working perfectly.

I have a centos server running apache.

In my httpd.conf file I have around 15 virtual hosts declared. About 10 work perfectly and about 5 seem not to read the .htaccess file at all.

**Here is what I have tried:**

**AllowOverride All**

All the vhost declrations look like this below with AllowOverride All set.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemail@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/websites/mywebsite/wwwroot
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    ErrorLog logs/mywebsite.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/mywebsite.com-access_log common
    <Directory "/var/www/websites/mywebsite/wwwroot”>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Permisions**

I have checked for the owner / permisions on the .htaccess file and relevant folders. This is consistent accross those that work and those that do not.

permisions for all sites, those that work and those that do not are like:

-rwxr-xr-x 1 nobody nobody 139 Oct 24 19:26 .htaccess

**Is the .htaccess being read?**

I the sites that work if I put gibberish in the file like

XXX CAUSE AN ERROR XXX

It gives the expected error in the working sites BUT nothing at all in the problem sites leading me to conclude the file is not being read at all.

**Silly Stuff**

- I have restarted apache
- .htaccess is spelled correctly.
- there are no overriding additional .htaccess files as far as i can tell.

Comment: What apache httpd version are you running? If you're on 2.4, there are some changes in directives. Also, anything in the global apache error log?

Comment: `<Directory "/var/www/websites/mywebsite/wwwroot”>` the final `”` is not correct, use `"`...

Comment: @kennet I am using Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)